# Why active in tailwindcss does not work in router-link?

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css, vue-router

```
          <router-link
            v-for="(item, i) in items"
            :key="i"
            class="text-base traking-wide font-normal mr-11 text-green-600 active:text-teal-600 hover:text-teal-600 transition duration-500"
            :to="item.to"
            >{{ item.title }}</router-link
          >
```

I try to find information in documentation, but couldn't find